# Using turbolinks with dynamic layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I am rendering different layouts for each controller like so:

```
# layouts/student.html.erb:
<% content_for :stylesheets do %>
  #menu_container {background-color: #3085BD;}
<% end %>
<% content_for :side_menu do %>
  <h4 style="text-align: center;"> STUDENTS</h4>
<% end %>
<%= render :template => 'layouts/application' %>
```

Using turbolinks, I've found that the layout is not changing when I navigate between different parts of the site. A page refresh fixes everything.

Is there a way to tell turbolinks to grab the layout along with the page content?

Comment: Turbolinks refreshes the entire body tag when you navigate pages. I'm assuming you are yielding your content_for inside the head tag? You could try moving it into a body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work by placing the following lines within the body tag of application.html.erb:

```
<%= content_for?(:side_menu) ? yield(:side_menu) : yield %>
<style type="text/css">
 <%= content_for?(:stylesheets) ? yield(:stylesheets) : yield %>
</style>
```